# Tensorflow build error on Orange Pi Pc Plus

Tags: tensorflow, arm, computer-vision, bazel, orange-pi

I'm trying to build `Tensorflow 1.7.1` on Orange Pi Pc Plus (Allwinner H3, ARM Cortex A7) running ARMBIAN 5.38 stable `Ubuntu 16.04.4` LTS 4.14.18-sunxi, and using `Bazel 0.10.0` [as per the official release](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources), I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/snowsquizy/tensorflow-on-orange-pi/blob/master/GUIDE.md), I built Bazel successfully, but when I try to build Tensorflow using `-mfpu=neon-vfpv4` flag for optimization:

```
bazel build -c opt --compilation_mode=opt --copt="-mfpu=neon-vfpv4" --copt="-funsafe-math-optimizations" --copt="-ftree-vectorize" --copt="-fomit-frame-pointer" --copt="-std=gnu99" --local_resources 500,2.0,1.0 --verbose_failures tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

I get the following error:

> bazel-out/arm-opt/bin/_solib_arm/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so:
>   error: undefined reference to 'png_init_filter_functions_neon'

I have tried installing both libpng16-dev and libpng12-dev, but the error still occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that until May 2018, the only official version of tensorflow that builds successfully on ARM without any modifications is revision *[d82b2f71b60d5fff48884c20c7b85e517330e91f](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/d82b2f71b60d5fff48884c20c7b85e517330e91f)*, according to [tensorflow's official CI server data](http://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-pi/238/), this is the latest successful build for ARM (Raspberry Pi) to date. The exact error reported in this question [shows up in the official nightly build of the next revision](http://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-pi/239/consoleFull).